# Parse iOS .strings file into perl hash

Tags: ios, regex, perl, localization

So I have .strings iOS localization file. This file format is like this:

```
/*some comment here*/
"key_one" = "value_one"

/*some comment here*/
"key_two" = "value_two"
```

I want to parse this into hash, probably using simple regex.

Any kind of help will be much apprichiated.

Comment: `"(\w+)"\s*=\s*"(\w+)"` . So `dict[$1] = $2`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/; 
my %hash = <> =~ m/"([^"]+)"      #something in quotes
                         \s*=\s*  # = and whitespace
                   "([^"]+)"      # something else in quotes
                            /gmx; # global, multiline, xtended

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key_two' => 'value_two',
          'key_one' => 'value_one'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<>) {
    if (m{^\s*"(\w+)"\s*=\s*"(\w+)"}) {
        $hash{$1} = $2;
    }
}
```

Gives

```
{
    'key_one' => 'value_one',
    'key_two' => 'value_two'
};
```